# Me sale Missing Keyword. Estoy usando Case anidados. Que parámetro me falta?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select 

    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L8_GENERO,
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L2_TIPO_PERSONA,
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L7_TIPO_DOC,
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L5_COD_PERSONA,
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L4_AP_PAT,
case 

when length(replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) > 0  
then 
     case  when length(replace(L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) = 10 
     then    to_date(replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-',''), 'DD/MM/YYYY') end,
    case  when length(replace(L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) = 9  then  to_date('0'||replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-',''), 'DD/MM/YYYY')  end
end, 
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L9_AP_MAT,
    'CIT',
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L3_NUM_DOC,
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L1_PRIMER_NOMBRE,
    L1_CDI_PERSONA.L6_NUM_HIST_CLIN,
    'I' INCREMENTAL_FLAG
from    CLARO.L1_CDI_PERSONA  L1_CDI_PERSONA
```

Answer (score 0):

Formateando un poco tu SQL (por favor toma la costumbre de indentar el SQL para mayor claridad), esto es lo que tienes con la expresión `CASE` anidada:

```
case 
  when length(replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) > 0  
  then case
         when length(replace(L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) = 10 
         then to_date(replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-',''), 'DD/MM/YYYY') end,
       case
         when length(replace(L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) = 9
         then to_date('0'||replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-',''), 'DD/MM/YYYY') end
end,
```

Estás usando `end,` y `case` en medio de tus condiciones, pero eso no debería estar allí. La expresión `CASE` anidada debería expresarse de la siguiente forma:

```
case 
  when length(replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) > 0  
  then case
         when length(replace(L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) = 10 
         then to_date(replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-',''), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
         when length(replace(L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-','')) = 9
         then to_date('0'||replace( L1_CDI_PERSONA.L10_dhclfna,'-',''), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
       end
end,
```